# send email with SMTP command, using socket programming in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to send email via socket programming using SMTP commands using socket in java. But i am unable to do so. The problem is in authentication may be.

I need SMTP commands to send email and to authenticate user over server.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks in Advance
Imran

Comment: COuld not use JAVA MAIL API :)

Answer (score 0):

Create Transport Object

```
Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", pProtocol);
        props.setProperty("mail.host", pHost);
        props.setProperty("mail.user", pUser);
        props.setProperty("mail.password", pPassword);

        mMailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        mMailSession.setDebug(true);

        try {
            mTransport = mMailSession.getTransport();
            mTransport.connect();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            mLog.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new MailException(e);
        }
```

Send mail

```
try {
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mMailSession);
            message.setSubject(pSubject);

            MimeBodyPart textPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            textPart.setContent(pContent, "text/html");

            Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
            mp.addBodyPart(textPart);

            message.setContent(mp);
            message.addFrom(new Address[] { new InternetAddress(pFrom) });

            for (int i = 0; i < pTo.length; i++) {
                String tTo = pTo[i];
                message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(tTo));
            }

            mTransport.sendMessage(message, message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));


        } catch (MessagingException me) {
            throw new MailException(me);
        }
```

**EDIT:**

After the comment from Thilo, i would like to append, that this solution depend on *com.sun.mail* and imports javax.mail.* classes.

Comment: This is using the Java Mail (javax.mail) packages (which is what you should do rather than talking to sockets directly)

Comment: Thank you for answer. But i am looking to send email via Socket Programming and i need SMTP commands in this regard. I want to use Gmail as my SMTP server.